# How to load Ck editor text directly on loading without showing html code in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, ckeditor

In My web application, i need to display text in ckeditor, while loading text into ckeditor it will shows suddenly HTML code after it will display text. I don't want to display HTML code at the time of loading i need to display text directly to ck editor how can i do this is it possible to solve this problem or not can anyone tell me.
My ckeditor:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="940px" Height="400px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

like this i passed data to ck editor

```
html = html.Replace("border-top-color:", "\"><hr /><border-top-color:");
CKEditor1.Text = html;
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you ask almost the same question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127198/how-to-remove-html-code-at-the-time-of-page-loads-ck-editor-loading-the-text-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CKEditor:CKEditorControl` controller creates a `<textarea>` element in html, and only when the document loads it changes the content of that `textarea` to the ckeditor instance.

If you can - change it to `<div>` element with `contenteditable="true"`. Another option is to hide that `textarea` using css:

```
textarea#CKEditor1 { display: none;}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working but i am forget to check the answer