# How to remove html code at the time of page loads ck editor loading the text in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ckeditor

In my wed application, I have one page it contains ck editor when i load that page ck editor showing some fraction of seconds HTML code after it will display text in ck editor. I need to stop that showing fraction of seconds HTML code how can i do this can anyone tell me.
My code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
         GetTemplate();
       }      
    }  
    Public void GetTemplate()
    {
       ShowTemplate();
    }
    Public void ShowTemplate()
    {
      //showTemplate code
      CKEditor1.Text = html;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditorYou can use a simple javascript trick to "hide" the CKEditor until it has been initialized.

```
<div style="height: 400px; width: 600px;">
    <div style="display: none" id="CKPlaceHolder">
        <asp:TextBox ID="CKEditorTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use 2 `<div>` elements. One to actually hide the editor and the first one as a placeholder to prevent the jumping of the content once the editor will be shown.

And then somewhere in JavaScript:

```
setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById('CKPlaceHolder').style.display = "block"; }, 500);
```

Comment: Hi VDWWD, my ck editor in .aspx in `<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" runat="server" Width="940px" Height="400px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>` is it possible to work

Comment: I think so. Just replace the TextBox with the editor Control and set the height in the first div to 940x400 to prevent jumping of the page content.

Comment: i take ck editor in place of textbox but when i select item from dropdown ck editor is fully loaded it means ck editor not completely display some fraction of seconds and after it will display. i don't need to load full editor i need to load only text on that.Thank you

Comment: I don't really understand this comment, but if you are loading a CK editor after a postback from a DropDown then you need to call that javascript function again.

Comment: I placed your code. But when i select the dropdown to display ckeditor text the ck editor control will full loads it not showing some fraction of seconds after it will display with text. see once i updated image links

Comment: Hi, I placed your code but loading it will take lot of time i took `<div><div><asp:UpdatePanel ID="update" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>My ckeditor Code  </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>`  and also i take `javascript code` like this i changed it will work

Comment: Thank you it will work, but i took ck editor control instead of your Textbox control